# K8s which access mode should be used in a persistentvolumeclaim for a database deployment?

Tags: database, postgresql, kubernetes, persistent-volume-claims

I want to store the data from a PostgreSQL database in a `persistentvolumeclaim`.
(on a managed Kubernetes cluster on Microsoft Azure)

**And I am not sure which access mode to choose.**

Looking at the available [access modes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes):

- `ReadWriteOnce`
- `ReadOnlyMany`
- `ReadWriteMany`
- `ReadWriteOncePod`

I would say, I should choose either `ReadWriteOnce` or `ReadWriteMany`.

Thinking about the fact that I might want to migrate the database pod to another node pool at some point, I would intuitively choose `ReadWriteMany`.

Is there any disadvantage if I choose `ReadWriteMany` instead of `ReadWriteOnce`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct with the migration, where the access mode should be set to `ReadWriteMany`.

Generally, if you have access mode `ReadWriteOnce` and a multinode cluster on microsoft azure, where multiple pods need to access the database, then the kubernetes will enforce all the pods to be scheduled on the node that mounts the volume first. Your node can be overloaded with pods. Now, if you have a `DaemonSet` where one pod is scheduled on each node, this could pose a problem. In this scenario, you are best with tagging the `PVC` and `PV` with access mode `ReadWriteMany`.

Therefore

- if you want multiple pods to be scheduled on multiple nodes and have access to DB, for write and read permissions, use access mode `ReadWriteMany`
- if you logically need to have pods/db on one node and know for sure, that you will keep the logic on the one node, use access mode `ReadWriteOnce`

Answer (score -1):

You should choose `ReadWriteOnce`.

I'm a little more familiar with AWS, so I'll use it as a motivating example.  In AWS, the easiest kind of persistent volume to get is backed by an Amazon Elastic Block Storage (EBS) volume.  This can be attached to only one node at a time, which is the `ReadWriteOnce` semantics; but, if nothing is currently using the volume, it can be detached and reattached to another node, and the cluster knows how to do this.

Meanwhile, in the case of a PostgreSQL database storage (and most other database storage), only one process can be using the physical storage at a time, on one node or several.  In the best case a second copy of the database pointing at the same storage will fail to start up; in the worst case you'll corrupt the data.

So:

- It never makes sense to have the volume attached to more than one pod at a time
- So it never makes sense to have the volume attached to more than one node at a time
- And `ReadWriteOnce` volumes are very easy to come by, but `ReadWriteMany` may not be available by default

This logic probably applies to most use cases, particularly in a cloud environment, where you'll also have your cloud provider's native storage system available (AWS S3 buckets, for example).  Sharing files between processes is fraught with peril, especially across multiple nodes.  I'd almost always pick `ReadWriteOnce` absent a really specific need to use something else.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge! The advantage I see in Azure Files/ReadWriteMany is that the database pod can be rescheduled by k8s to different nodes. So if the node, where the DB pod was originally deployed becomes busy the DB pod is not restricted to stick with that node.

Comment: That should be possible with ReadWriteOnce volumes as well (though my experience is with AWS/EKS and not AKS).  If the underlying volume type can be unmounted from one node and remounted on another, then the cluster can move the data to follow the workload.

Comment: Is there any drawback why not to use Azure Files/ReadWriteMany? The Many/Once suffix refers to the number of nodes, not pods, anyway. So neither really prevents multiple pods/processes from accessing the PVC. 

The fact that multiple pods can access it allows for more complex setups. For example you could have another pod which moves log files periodically or checks the used disk space.